# Icons for android app

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

I need to remove headers from icons that i am using for my android app. I am creating the icons in gimp. What should I use to remove headers or unnecessary data from my icons?

Also i am storing the icons in the mdpi,ldpi and hdpi according to their sizes. Do I need to specify about my icons anywhere in my app. ?
Thanks.

Comment: A nice guideline for icons: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define it in your AndroidManifest.xml that´s enough

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon"
```

the diferent devices will take their correct icons according their screensize or resolution.